# How to fix problem with postion JPanel on JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have some problem with a JPanel position and gaps on a JLayeredPane.

I created four a JLayeredPane and inserted a JPanel to  it  with some gaps between borders (code below).

After, I checked  gaps size. They aren't equal along the horizontal axis.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class setting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //get size window
        Dimension tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int  width = (int) tk.width;
        int  hight = (int) tk.height;


        // setting for window 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4, 0, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 



        // set panels for window
        JLayeredPane panel_0 = new JLayeredPane();
        panel_0.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel_0.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(panel_0);



        JLayeredPane panel_1 = new JLayeredPane();
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel_1.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(panel_1);

        JLayeredPane panel_2 = new JLayeredPane();
        panel_2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel_2.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(panel_2);


        JLayeredPane panel_3 = new JLayeredPane();
        panel_3.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel_3.setOpaque(true);
        frame.add(panel_3);

        //insert_panels
        JLayeredPane insert_panel_0 = new JLayeredPane();
        insert_panel_0.setBackground(Color.black);
        insert_panel_0.setOpaque(true);

        insert_panel_0.setBounds(width/400,hight/200,width/4 - width/200,hight/10);

        JLayeredPane insert_panel_1= new JLayeredPane();
        insert_panel_1.setBackground(Color.black);
        insert_panel_1.setOpaque(true);
        insert_panel_1.setBounds(width/400,hight/200,width/4 - width/200,hight/10);

        panel_1.add(insert_panel_0);
        panel_2.add(insert_panel_1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Could you help me?

Are exist other methods for gaps and position JPanel on JLayeredPane?

Comment: You need to describe more of what you are trying to accomplish.  Why are you using  JLayeredPanes?  What is the final frame supposed to look like.

Comment: Seems like you found a solution in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500171/how-to-setting-setborder-for-window-application. If so then delete this question so people don't spend time trying to answer a question that has already been solved. If  not, then you need to clarify the question.