# How to setting setBorder for window application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I tried create some application for monitoring network. I'm going to create 4 `JPanels` and insert, for example, panels  `insert_panel_0`, `insert_panel_2`  to  `panel_2`.I can't  setting my borders between `insert_panel_0`, `insert_panel_2`. I have vertical gaps,  but i don't have horizontal gaps.

Could you help me solve it?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class setting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //get size window
        Dimension tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int  width = (int) tk.width;
        int  hight = (int) tk.height;



        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4, 0, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 



        // set panels for window
        JPanel panel_0 = new JPanel();
        panel_0.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_0.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));
        panel_0.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(panel_0);



        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel_1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        frame.add(panel_1);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        panel_2.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(panel_2);


        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_3.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        panel_3.setBackground(Color.blue);

        frame.add(panel_3);

        JPanel insert_panel_0 = new JPanel();
        insert_panel_0.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width/4, (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
        insert_panel_0.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel_2.add(insert_panel_0);

        JPanel insert_panel_1 = new JPanel();
        insert_panel_1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width/4, (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
        insert_panel_1.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel_2.add(insert_panel_1);    

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert_panel_0.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width/4, (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
```

The problem is your width calculation. When you divide by 4 the width of each black child panel is the width of the entire parent panel. This causes two problems:

1. The child panel can't fit into the parent panel with the 20 pixel border, so it is painted at the panels edge
2. The FlowLayout will then automatically wrap the second panel to the next row. So the panels are displayed on two rows.

The solution is to improve your width calculation for example:

```
insert_panel_0.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width/12, (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
```

Now the two panels will appear on the same row.

If you want a gap between the two black panels then you also need:

```
//panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout has methods for setting horizontal and vertical gaps: `setHgap(hgap)` and `setVGap(vgap)`. Or you can provide them as you create the layout in a constructor: `new GridLayout(rows, cols, hgap, vgap)`

hope it helps.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I  don't have horizontal gaps

Comment: Also, the GridLayou cell sizes are the same. This is not appropriate for my case.

Comment: In a GridLayout, each cell is exactly the same size.

Comment: And try setting content pane of the frame like `frame.getContentPane().setLayout`

Comment: @Zero12 *Also, the GridLayou cell sizes are the same* - well, you question was NOT about this. We can't read your mind to guess what you want. This issue should have been stated in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GridBagLayout** and utilize **Insets**. However this brings about a new problem:

*You need to take into account* the size of the insets when calculating the Dimension for `insert_panel_0` and `insert_panel_1`, because if the total size (*insert_panel_0_size + insert_panel_1_size + Insets*) is greater than the parent (panel_2_size), `insert_panel_0` and `insert_panel_1` will not size properly.

Constructor and description: (from java-docs):

> `Insets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)`
>   Creates and initializes a new Insets object with the specified top, left, bottom,
>   and right insets.

Unrelated to your question, but in Java GUI you should **always call your GUI from the event-dispatching thread**. This will help you avoid unwanted behavior when you start getting more complex/dynamically updated values in your GUI.

Your modified code (you'll have to play around with your Dimension formula, I commented it out because: lazy):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createGUI() {

        //get size window
        Dimension tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int  width = (int) tk.width;
        int  hight = (int) tk.height;



        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4, 0, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 



        // set panels for window
        JPanel panel_0 = new JPanel();
        panel_0.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_0.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));
        panel_0.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(panel_0);



        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel_1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        frame.add(panel_1);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel_2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        panel_2.setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(panel_2);


        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel_3.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20,20, 20));      
        panel_3.setBackground(Color.blue);

        frame.add(panel_3);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,5,0,5); // Horizontal padding only

        JPanel insert_panel_0 = new JPanel();
        //insert_panel_0.setPreferredSize( new Dimension((width/4), (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
        insert_panel_0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        insert_panel_0.setBackground(Color.black);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel_2.add(insert_panel_0, gbc);

        JPanel insert_panel_1 = new JPanel();
        //insert_panel_1.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width/4 - 10, (int) Math.round( hight*0.05)));
        insert_panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        insert_panel_1.setBackground(Color.black);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel_2.add(insert_panel_1, gbc);    

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zero12 Please accept the answer if the question is closed - and thank you for posting readable, runnable code. :~p